# Connecting to MongoDB with Mongoose in docker-compose containers fail with useUnifiedTopology

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I have a NodeJS Application that connects to a MongoDB server.

Both the node application and MongoDB server are served in a docker container (with `docker-compose`)

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
 redis:
  image: "redis:alpine"
  ports:
   - "6379:6379"
  expose:
   - 6379
  restart:
   always
  container_name: redis-server

 mongo:
  image: "mongo"
  command: mongod --bind_ip_all --replSet rs8
  volumes:
   - c:\mongo\data:/data/db
  ports:
   - "27017:27017"
  expose:
   - 27017
  restart:
   always
  container_name: mongo-server
   
 accounts-service:
  depends_on:
    - redis
    - mongo
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: GenericNodeJSDockerfile
  container_name: accounts-service
  ports:
   - "8001:8001"
```

In the node app, the connection in mongo looks like this:

```js
const m = require('mongoose')
const connectionConfig = {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
};

let connectionString = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/mydb/replicaSet=rs8';

m.connect(connectionString , connectionConfig).then(_ => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB")
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Failed connecting to MongoDB: " + err);
});
```

And the error that is thrown is:

`Failed connecting to MongoDB: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`

But when I'm commenting the row contains `useUnifiedTopology` option, the connection succeeds.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that I had a wrong `hosts` file configuration that made this issue.

Comment: Sorry @Erez.S, can you give more detailed answer on what was wrong in your case? Struggling with same magic, but don't see anything suspicious in my /etc/hosts file.